# Text that can be edited & saved in a webpage

Tags: php, text

I'm not really sure where to start on this:

I'm looking to have a page on a website that is just a few words, I want it so you are able to edit and add to it in the browser, and then for that to be saved, for example >

Webpage just has 'hello' written in the middle of it, the user is able to click that and overwrite it with 'goodbye'. That is then saved so you the next user to the page will see 'goodbye'.

I understand this can get out of hand with anons and stuff, but its going to be used privately..

I am guessing PHP is the best route for this? Doing it without a database would be super if possible. If someone could point me in the right direction would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe an existing *Wiki* package would suit your needs better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally `PHP` and `MYSQL` would be the best option **OR** saving the text into a `txt` document with `PHP`.

Take a look at this `Mysqli` tutorial for inserting data [Link >>](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

This is also a good tutorial for the `PHP` `fwrite()` function, if writing to a txt file is what you would prefer: [Link >>](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)

I would also check out this `jQuery` plugin, it sounds like what you want. It allows you to edit an `HTML` element by clicking, typing and then clicking back off (no page refresh):

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: Thanks, I think the jquery plugin is all i require, seems to do everything I need.

Comment: no problem! if theres anything else I can do to help just let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you have to decide **where you want to save the data/pages**.

   You have to use a server-side technology (such as PHP, Perl, C, Ruby, ....) here:

   - In the database
   - As files
2. Now, you should implement the **save-and-open API** for the client
3. Write the **client**.

   If you really want direct editing in the text, you could use the `content-editable` attribute (which was standardized in HTML 5), example here: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable.


   Do you want your users to be able to insert new elements (i.e. HTML tags) or to just edit some text parts?
   If you choose the former option, then I would suggest you using something like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or a simple markup language such as [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (also used here on StackOverflow).

Comment: thanks for this, will read up about this too!